# Good wiki software for both internal docs and customer-facing technical documentation?

Tags: wiki, documentation

#### Context

I work for a heavy equipment company, and we currently have all our documentation as PDFs on a big network drive. This works alright for the gigantic mass of technical documentation (hydraulic/electrical schematics, drawings, etc) we have, but it's a little cumbersome even for that. But it's a total failure for internal documentation.

#### Wishlist

We're interested in having a wiki for "tribal knowledge" stuff and some basic onboarding info, and also a customer-facing service manual site that allows for richer content than traditional service manual PDFs. It would be nice if these were handled by the same product, but it's not a hard requirement. My approximate feature wish-list:

- Configurable authentication, so we can have a "technician portal" that both engineers and techs have access to, and an "internal engineering docs" that only engineers see
- Version control, but preferably not just command-line Git, because the mechanical engineers will hate me
- Great support for tables
- Ability to easily link/import PDFs from our existing network drive of drawings. Windows tells me we have about 7TB of PDF drawings currently. It would be absolutely incredible to just "link" one like `http://ourwikiserver/someMagicMacroForThePDFs/network/drive/path/to/drawing.pdf`.
- Comments/change requests on pages, to encourage documentation improvement

#### I've considered...

I'm an electrical engineer but I've got a lot of software dev experience, so I've used Confluence and mkdocs, and a tiny bit of GitBook.

I think mkdocs is too simple, and I think any system that requires raw command-line interaction with Git is a giant risk with a dozen MechE's who are unfamiliar.

And frankly, I hate the UI on Confluence. The actual page editor feels cumbersome, dunno why it can't just be Markdown.

Considered GitBook but not sure how we'd integrate it with our existing mass of drawings.

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance!